# How do I connect to a MySQL database in my web application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I would like to give a web application access to update and retrieve information from a MySQL database.  I have server space through HostGator and have created a sample MySQL database that I would like to access using via an npm package that facilitates using MySQL in a Node/express environment. I have created a database using HostGator's built in MySQL database wizard and have populated it using phpMyAdmin which is HostGator's database manager. How do I specify the location of this database to my application so that it can access it? The npm package I am using has a function to connect to a MySQL database given 'host', 'user', and 'password' parameters.  I know what the user and password data are, but what would the 'host' be?  I apologize if my question is vague, but I have not been able to find any useful information on this topic because I am unsure of exactly what to look for, so thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: The host is the domain name or IP address of the database server.

Comment: Ok,  the location of the db I've created seems to be the local host. Does this  mean that the db is stored on my computer?  Clearly that's no good for deployment?  Where do people normally store databases and how do they move them to this location?

Comment: `localhost` is a reference to your computer. Since you are hosting on something called HostGator, they likely provided you a URL to connect to their phpMyAdmin tool. When you log into that phpMyAdmin, look at the URL in the address bar.

Comment: To answer your other questions, most developers will work on a localhost copy of the database, then deploy their changes to a test server and finally to a production server once quality has been assured. There are numerous ways of getting code from local to remote.

Comment: Thanks, things are becoming clearer.  What does it mean to have a local instance of a MySQL DB?  I know that my server has MySQL installed on it, do I need to install it on my computer to use a local instance? phpMyAdmin says that the server for the DB I created is the local host, if I feed a given 'connect to database' function host = localhost, and the database name, will it know where to find the data? Sorry again for my vagueness, still trying to wrap my head around how this works.

Comment: You can install MySQL on your computer and run databases from it. HostGator has MySQL installed and is running the databases for you. I have never used HostGator though, so I don't know how much more help I can be. Start with `localhost` as your hostname and see if it works? If not, log into your phpMyAdmin and use the domain name portion of the URL.